# function getting stuck in a loop

Tags: c

I am doing a school project in C and I am stuck at this puzzle.
So, we need to implement a message passing system using sockets for 100 users.
I am storing my users' data in this struct.

```
typedef struct user
{
   char username[20];
   int online;        //flag value 1 = online, 0 = offline
   msg *message_list;
   int message_count;
}
```

And one service we need to implement is to pull a list of all currently connected users. I have written this function for that task.

```
void all_connected(char buf[2300])
{
    printf("\n entering all_connected for %d iterations",user_count);
    int i, count = 1;
    char tmp[25];
    for (i=0; i<user_count; i++)
    {
        if(users[i] -> online == 1)
        {            
            sprintf(tmp, "\n\t%d. %s", count++, users[i] -> username);
            strcat(buf, tmp);
        }
    }
    printf("\n exiting all_connected");
}
```

Now for some weird reason, when I call this function when the service is requested, it prints the first printf (entering all_connected for x iterations); but it doesn't print the one that I've put on the last line.
Does this mean that the function is getting stuck on some line? I checked and it is iterating 'user_count' times, but never coming on the last line.

What might be a reason for this happening?

Comment: Add some `printf()` calls inside the loop and the `if` statement.

Comment: I did have a print inside the if statement. It is finishing all the iterations.

Comment: You should show that in your code here.

Comment: Also, add a temporary `flush()` call after the last `printf()` to see if the problem is just that the buffer isn't being flushed.

Comment: `char tmp[25];` is not long enough to accommodate `char username[20];` plus up to 7 more characters. Nor is `char buf[2300]` as that only allows 23 bytes per user (if that is what was passed, the array length in the function argument is not relevant). Also you must initialise `buf` before passing it to `strcat`, the first time.

Comment: Note that the dot `.` and arrow `->` operators bind very tightly and should not be surrounded by spaces.

Comment: It is more usual to place the `newline` at the end of a `printf` format string, not at the beginning. If you should use `printf` cues while debugging, the lack of a terminating `\n` can cause a lot of confusion, since the line might not have been printed when the error you are debugging occurs.

Comment: This isn't the reason why your program isn't working but you started declaring new type with typedef but there is no type name.

Comment: Add an `fflush(stdout)`, because until you print a newline, it's not guaranteed to flush (and even then, that might be implementation-defined -- but all implementations I know of have that). If it doesn't flush, it won't print to your console.

Answer (score 0):

This format string `"\n\t%d. %s"` (assuming up to 20 characters per user) will need a 26-bytes (ASCII) buffer. Here's why:

1. 1 or 2 bytes for the `"\n"` (depending on the system)
2. up to 2 bytes for `"%d"` (presuming you count up to 99)
3. 2 bytes for `". "`
4. up to 20 bytes for `"%s"`

Your temporary buffer `char tmp[25];` is too narrow - has to be at least 26 bytes big (counting the NULL-terminator).

If you have a list of 100 users that would require a total buffer of at least 2601 bytes but from the looks of it you are only providing the function with the buffer of the size 2300. Side note, just specifying the function's input parameter as being `char buf[2300]` doesn't do anything to actually **allocate** that buffer. You'd have to make sure you supply the necessary buffer when you call your function.

The reason you are not getting the second `printf()` is because your program terminates before reaching that point. The reason for termination is *memory access violation* - that happens when you try to write something into the memory that doesn't belong to your buffers (either a small one or the bug one)

Comment: The problem should be more at tmp variable rather than buf.  buf variable is really sending in a pointer so it will keep on strcat() onto it.  There should have been segmentation fault if tmp variable overflows.